# Error while running gulp plugin

Tags: gulp

I downloaded shakyShane's plugin: https://github.com/shakyShane/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync.
While I am running gulp in directory with it, I am getting this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgKt4.png.

I installed pygments before, because last error told, that I haven't installed this gem.
I am windows 7 user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found solution for all problems I had. First of all, I uninstalled Nodejs and Railsinstaller (windows user). Next deleted all data of npm in roaming folder. After that I installed node and railsinstaller, opened cmd and:

```
gem install jekyll
```

And:

```
gem install pygments
```

After that:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Next I edited _config.yml file in master directory of plugin, changed default highlighter from pygments to rouge, and installed redcarpet gem by running this command:

```
gem install redcarpet
```

And that's it, gulp is running properly on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem with ruby gems - pygments.
When you installed Ruby did you check the option to add it to your path?

[I found this tutorial to get jekyll setup on windows](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/1-ruby-and-devkit/)

Comment: Yes, I checked that option.